REST endpoints stop working after adding flowable spring boot starter dependency
I am attempting to use the flowable library, however when I add the dependencies my existing and working rest api endpoints stop working. They return a 500 error and in the terminal it states:

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[/dmn-api/*]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.

The specific dependency that causes this is:
implementation("org.flowable:flowable-spring-boot-starter-rest:7.1.0")
Was hoping someone here might be able to describe what the problem really is and how to best resolve it.
